# Kendo Grid query is slow due to row_number()

Tags: c#, linq, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**Problem**

I have a Kendo grid which is using LINQ to fetch data from SQL Server view. The base table has hundred of thousands of rows. When I run the view in the database it returns the data in a flash but when I load the grid it is taking 30 seconds to load 5 rows.

**What I have done so far?**

I ran SQL Profile and got to the bottom of the issue. It is due to `row_number()` in the translated SQL query. If I remove `row_number()` from the translated query then I get the results pretty fast.

**My assumption**

I am assuming that Kendo is adding `row_number()` to the query (please correct me if I am wrong).

**How do I fix it?**

How do I make it quicker? Do I need to override something in Kendo (for example, a Kendo method or a Kendo Property)?

Comment: I've never seen it do that by default.  Can you post your code?  Also, are you using `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` and what data access?

Comment: You want to display only sequence number in the Kendo Grid? There is not any connection between Kendo Grid and Row_number in sql. May be probelm is somewhere else.

Comment: Good point. I thought Kendo was using `row_number()` for paging. From the query: `WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 485`. But still you guys made a valid point and I am looking into it now.

Comment: How does your code look like? Paste your action method here.